# Remove all characters except two letters

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am looking for a logic to remove all characters in a string except AD & Numeric values.

Examples

| String | Expected Result |
| --- | --- |
| AD-892839 statement | AD-892839 |
| BOD AD-89283 | AD-89283 |
| BOD AD-89283 ACGD | AD-89283 |

I have tried to write a logic using regexp_replace but didn't get expected results.

In few cases we are receiving the transaction like AD-89823/1, AD-898232/2, AD-2283/5, etc.

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| AD-892839 statement | AD-892839 |
| BOD AD-89283 | AD-89283 |
| BOD AD-89283 ACGD | AD-89283 |
| BOD AD-89283/1,AD-89284/2,AD-89285/1 ACGD | AD-89283/1,AD-89284/2,AD-89285/1 |
| AD-89283/1,AD-89284/2,AD-89285/1 TIOL | AD-89283/1,AD-89284/2,AD-89285/1 |

Answer (score 3):

```
with data as
(
  select 'AD-892839 statement' as text               from dual union all
  select 'BOD AD-89283'                              from dual union all
  select 'BOD AD-89283 ACGD'                         from dual union all
  select 'BOD AD-89283/1,AD-89284/2,AD-89285/1 ACGD' from dual union all
  select 'AD-89283/1,AD-89284/2,AD-89285/1 TIOL'     from dual
)
select regexp_substr(data.text, '(AD-([[:digit:]]|/)+|,)+')
from data;

REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA.TEXT,'(AD-([[:DIGIT:]]
-----------------------------------------
AD-892839
AD-89283
AD-89283
AD-89283/1,AD-89284/2,AD-89285/1
AD-89283/1,AD-89284/2,AD-89285/1
```

Comment: Hi Bala, I have tried with the given logic - regexp_substr(text, 'AD-([[:digit:]]|/|,)+') but it's not considering AD- for the second & third time. It's reterives only first time i.e AD-89283/1,